# How to upgrade angularjs version in ionic v1 app

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am looking for a way to upgrade angularjs version in ionic v1 app. Because of Google Play Console Security alert for my applications.
I got SNYK warning and warning is SNYK-npm:angular:20180202.
SNYK suggestion: Upgrade angular to version 1.6.9 or higher.

My question is, how can i upgrade angularjs version in ionic v1 app?
Thanks.

Comment: you can change in you package.json file or link library file in your index

Comment: Alternatively you can create new Ionic 1 Project and replace www folder with yours. and install plugins and other dependencies manually.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have installed `bower` and can execute `bower` command, you can update angular lib in your ionic v1 project by using this command:

```
bower install angular@1.7.8
bower install angular-animate@1.7.8
bower install angular-sanitize@1.7.8
```

Hope this helps.